# List all direct and transitive project dependencies of a given project (.??proj)

Tags: msbuild, f#-fake

I'm in the process of introducing FAKE as a build tool.
[ProjectScaffold](https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold) looks like a great start in addition to the FAKE help.

However in my case, listing relevant csproj/fsproj files cannot easily be achieved with  `!! "src/**/*.??proj"` as used in the "AssemblyInfo" target for instance. The reason being that my repo contains code for different products + common code, not properly laid out under dedicated directories.

My plan is to start from the product's entry assembly and navigate recursively its projects dependencies to yield the full list of projects involved in the given product's build.

I believe MSBuild should be able to help with this. Obviously, I want to avoid building everything twice: once to get the list of projects before altering their assembly info and then the actual build.
Or maybe there are helpers in FAKE that could help with this task?

Any other advice when it comes to handling different product builds living under the same repo is welcome. Note that breaking down this repo into smaller repos (one per product) might be considered in the future, but not at the moment.

Comment: Are you planning on gated commit as part of this? Why would you not just build the whole solution to verify the code has not broken any parts of it.
Otherwise why structuring your project to have unrelated code under same solution?

Comment: @AlexM No, not really planning on gated commits. There are several solutions in this repo. I wonder how much benefit I get from invoking MSBuild on the solution rather than on the entry assemblies directly. In my opinion some of the solutions have become unnecessary complex including/excluding projects based on config|platform.

Comment: If it is a solution you pass into msbuild, then it will build all projects within. Otherwise there would be some naming pattern or similar to identify the projects required for the build?